# 2D binary matrix conversion to an black and white image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a 2D binary matrix. How can I convert this into a black and white image?

Comment: A 2D binary matrix is a way to represent a black and white image.

Comment: please research before u ask questions

Answer (score 5):

you should write

```
I = mat2gray(A)
```

you can make a

```
imshow(I)
```

to see it working.